# Cluster(Mat) function taking too long (opencv)

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to make a dictionary using BOWKMeansTrainer class: i have 63 images for training of different size, but the average size is around 700x900 pixels. The function cluster(...) is actually taking a lot of time, it's already 5 hours that is running. How much do you think I still have to wait? Is there a way to make it faster?

```
TermCriteria tc(1, 100, 0.001); //term criteria type, 100 iterations with 0.001 accuracy
int retries = 1;
int flags = KMEANS_PP_CENTERS;
printf("Kmeans Clustering descriptors \n");
BOWKMeansTrainer bowTrainer(dictSize, tc, retries, flags); //create a Trainer
Mat myDictionary = bowTrainer.cluster(newFeatures); //start clustering
printf("dictionary rows = %d  cols = %d\n", myDictionary.rows, myDictionary.cols);
FileStorage fs("myDictionary.yml", FileStorage::WRITE); //store dictionary in a file
fs << "vocabulary" << myDictionary;
fs.release();
```

Comment: yes. it is supposed to be slow. what hardware platform are you running on? for some lower spec PC 5 hour is normal.

Comment: It's a ASUS laptop, not very powerful! Whataver it has finally finished, so I dont have any other way to make it faster?

Comment: Not that easy. best is to use server room PC. That can accelerate the training within 1hour.  not sure this function implemented GPU version or not, if yes, then GPU can accelerate also